# is there a way to avoid 'column not allowed here' error when inserting rows

Tags: sql, oracle11g

so i was making a table which generates receipt numbers under this conditions:

1. first 2 letters should be 'HL' if account type is Home Loan and 'SL' if student loan
2. next 2 letters should be from lastname and be padded with 0's from left
   here's my code and error whenever i insert rows:

```
insert into processedaccounts
values (30, (substr(accounttype,1,2) || (lastname,1,2) || RPAD(receiptnumber_seq.nextval9,'0')), 'Metropolis', 'Home Loan', 'Adam', 'Smith');
```

> Error Report -
> SQL ERROR: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

> 984. 00000 - "column not allowed here"

how should i modify my query to avoid the 'column not allowed here' error

Comment: what are the columns in processedaccounts  table?

Comment: How are you getting values for accounttype,lastname and receiptnumber_seq. They are not referred from any table in your query

Comment: the columns are requestid, receipt number, city, account type, firstname and lastname

Comment: oh right, i forgot the reference table. the reference table request accounts have columns: request id, account type, firstname and lastname

Answer (score 0):

Your RPAD function is not constructed correctly. The function format is:

```
RPAD( string1, padded_length [, pad_string] )
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query :

- substr function for account type is wrong , you should get first character and first character after space
- RPAD function is wrong
- No substr function for last name
- The Reference table is missing
- Values should be selected from reference table

I have corrected them and here is the final query, change table and column names as per your requirement

```
insert into processedaccounts
select  requestid,
        substr(account_type,1,1)||SUBSTR(account_type, Instr(account_type, ' ', 1, 1) +1,1) || substr(lastname,1,2) || RPAD(receiptnumber2.nextval,9,0) ,
        city, 
        account_type,
        firstname,
        lastname
from request_accounts
where request_accounts.requestid = 30;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot refer to `accounttype` or `lastname` as you are not `SELECT`ing from a row, you are `CREATE`ing a new row. You will need to use literals instead:

```sql
insert into processedaccounts (
  requestid,
  receiptnumber,
  city,
  accounttype,
  firstname,
  lastname
) values (
  30, 
  'HL' || 'SM' || RPAD(receiptnumber_seq.nextval, 9, '0'),
  'Metropolis',
  'Home Loan',
  'Adam',
  'Smith'
);
```

If you are getting the values from a table then:

```sql
insert into processedaccounts (
  requestid,
  receiptnumber,
  city,
  accounttype,
  firstname,
  lastname
) 
SELECT requestid, 
       CASE accounttype
       WHEN 'Home Loan' THEN 'HL'
       WHEN 'Student Loan' THEN 'SL'
       END
       || UPPER(SUBSTR(lastname, 1, 2))
       || RPAD(receiptnumber_seq.nextval, 9, '0'),
       'Metropolis',
       accounttype,
       firstname,
       lastname
FROM   requestaccounts
WHERE  somecondition = something;
```